# electron installer for windows

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor, hybrid

I have started to write a hybrid desktop app with Electron using the prebuilt package. Now I want to create an installer for the app in windows, I read the packaging and distribution documents on atom documentation but it seems really difficult to understand the process. can anybody help with this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. You'll have to package the installer separately, but it's not too big of a problem!

Go ahead and do a build of your application, and you should get a folder for windows, with the .exe and a bunch of additional files.

I used a tool called Inno Setup Compiler: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php#qsp

If you use the wizard and follow the steps, it's pretty simple. It'll build out a custom setup installer so your users can just download the installer and they're good to go! :)

Something to note. When you get to the Application Files, browse for the .exe and make sure to `Add folder...` and select the entire win32 folder, since it's needed for the install. :)

Comment: I managed to pack the application but then I have noticed that I need an update for my application every now and then, so the separated installer wouldn't work that way right ?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to manually repackage every time. The option 'electron-builder' might be the way to go, and Alessandro linked above. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder), it let's you create the installer bundled with the squirrel package (for auto updating the app)

Comment: still can't get that right :\

could you please attach an example or a reference for a tutorial?